# Android studio not displaying any attributes for recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

There are no attributes displaying for recycleview. even I tried to type the xml code android studio IntelliSense not suggest any attribute.

[this is how it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR4nX.png)

this is the **build.gradle** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
            minSdkVersion 22
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    }
```

this is xml part of this project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this for every other Attributes? 
I think, you need to clean the cache of your Android Studio. Try to do `File > Invalidate Caches / Restarts` and then check out.

Comment: this happen only for recycleview Attributes